# Lightning datatable button position

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

the lightning datatable inline edit Save/Cancel buttons appear on the bottom of the table how do i get them to show at the top of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but I can say with 99% certainty is that you can’t do this without some crazy JS and CSS.

I would personally avoid that and accept the fact that the buttons are at the bottom and focus on the things that I can change.

Comment: Because of the encapsulation of component internals, you can't do it even with some crazy JS and CSS (I like the phrasing, by the way).